# Android reading array returned from php

Tags: php, android, arrays

I am reading a php response in an android method.

**PHP**

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        $status = "Success!";
        echo "Success!";
    } else {
        echo "Login failed";
    }
```

**Android**

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(result.equals("Success!")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent goToWelcomePage = new Intent(context, welcome.class);
            context.startActivity(goToWelcomePage);
        } else if (result.equals("User Created")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "User Created.  Login Now.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent goToLoginPage = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(goToLoginPage);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The above script is working without any trouble.

However, I want to read an array of results.I tried this in PHP.

```
$status = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    $status = "Success!";
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$status,"name"=>$username));   
} else {
    $status = "Login failed";
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$status));
}
```

Not sure how to read this in Android. Besides, I am not sure if the above php is the right way to return results to android.

Comment: the php part is irrelevant. You may want to edit your question to include the json response your server is returning for this call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem in the PHP code, at least it can return a correct json as you expected if what you want is:

```
{"result":"Success!","name":"YOUR_LOGIN_NAME"}
```

or

```
{"result":"Login failed"}
```

In Android, you should use a json parser library to parser the "result" such as Gson(https://github.com/google/gson).

you can create a response class like:

```
class MyResponse {
    String result;
    String name;
}
```

then you can simply call in your code:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyResponse response = gson.fromJson(result, MyResponse.class);
    switch (response.result) {
        case "Success!":
            // do something when login success
            // can call response.name here to read the login name
            break;
        case "Login failed":
            // do something when login failed
            break;
        // and more...
    }
```

And if you are interested in a modern HTTP client, you can have a look:
okhttp (https://github.com/square/okhttp)
retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Comment: Thank you...your code helped.  I made couple of changes to suit my requirement.